# Validação de formulário PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Gostaria de saber se tem como inserir algum script dentro do contact.php para, antes de fazer ação de enviar os dados para o email, verificar os campos do formulário. Desde já, grato!

Segue aqui o formulário:

```
<form action="contact.php" target="_blank" method="post" id="form-contato">
        Faça o download grátis aqui! <br/><br/>
        Basta preencher o formulário para baixar a áudio história: <br/><br/><br/>
        Nome: 
        <br/>
        <input name="nome" size=56 id="name_edit"> 
        <br/><br/> 
        Email: 
        <br/>
        <input name="email" size=56 id="email_edit">
        <br/><br/>
        7+4?: 
        <br/>         
        <input name="mensagem" size=56 id="mens_edit">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="BAIXAR AUDIOBOOK" name="submit" id="button">
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <p id="text_edit"><a href="politicaprivacidade.php">Politica de Privacidade</a>.<br/><br/>
        Prometemos não utilizar suas informações de contato para enviar qualquer tipo de SPAM.</p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Segue aqui o contact.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
  require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['nome'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['mensagem'])){
 $fields=[
    'nome'=>$_POST['nome'],
    'email'=>$_POST['email'],
    'mensagem'=>$_POST['mensagem']
 ];
 $m=new PHPMailer;
 $m->isSMTP();
 $m->SMTPDebug = 1;
 $m->SMTPAuth=true;
 $m->Host='smtp.zoho.com';
 $m->Username='#';
 $m->Password='#';
 $m->SMTPSecure='ssl';
 $m->Port=465;

 $m->isHTML(true);
 $m->Subject ='E-mail eviado pelo site';
 $m->Body='De:'.$fields['nome'].'('.$fields['email'].')<p>Mensagem: <br>'.$fields['mensagem'].'</p>';
 $m->SetFrom('sac@evoxtech.com.br','SAC');
 $m->AddAddress('#','#');
 if ($m->send()) {
     header('#');
     die();
 }
}

header ('#');
```

Comment: Sim, tem, mas você esqueceu de detalhar quais verificações deseja fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validação mais simples seria, adicionar um required aos inputs, assim ele só enviaria se ao menos os inputs estivessem carregados, ou pode inserir código JavaScript para verificar, conforme abaixo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("form").submit(function(e) {
    if( $('#nome').val().length < 5  ){
   alert('O nome precisa ter mais que 5 letras');
   return false;
    }
   
         e.preventDefault();
      });
 });
</script>


    <form action="contact.php" target="_blank" method="post" id="form-contato">
            Faça o download grátis aqui! <br/><br/>
            Basta preencher o formulário para baixar a áudio história: <br/><br/><br/>
            Nome: 
            <br/>
            <input name="nome" id="nome" size=56 id="name_edit" required> 
            <br/><br/> 
            Email: 
            <br/>
            <input name="email" size=56 id="email_edit" required>
            <br/><br/>
            7+4?: 
            <br/>         
            <input name="mensagem" size=56 id="mens_edit" required>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="BAIXAR AUDIOBOOK" name="submit" id="button">
            <br/><br/><br/>
            <p id="text_edit"><a href="politicaprivacidade.php">Politica de Privacidade</a>.<br/><br/>
            Prometemos não utilizar suas informações de contato para enviar qualquer tipo de SPAM.</p>
        </form>
      </div>
```